# Creation of Power BI Matrix with Two Segmented Tables with Distrinct Count Measure

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, semantic-segmentation

Currently, I am working on a matrix visual containing two fixed segment tables (Total sales and Student population) with a measure. The segmented tables contain A - D segmented column and Min/Max column of the range of the segment per A-D segment. As you know, both segment tables will be in rows and columns in the matrix.

I'd like to create a dynamic matrix with two segmented tables and a measure that will be dynamically changed based on the selection of slicers. However, the following are my impediments.

1. Measure creation: I need to have a new measure. As the two segmented tables do not have any data modeling with other dim and fact tables, the measure needs to meet the segment conditions for both total sales and population tables and still output the distinct count of sales districts. For example, if I choose a product group A slicer, the matrix will show me the distinct count of sales districts that purchased product group A based on the segmented sales and population condition. For example, we have 11 sales districts that are in the "A" sales segment (>$ 25,000) and "A" population (>30,000). Also, we have 30 sales districts that are in the "C" sales segment (>$1,000) and "B" population (5,000).

Below are both segmented tables.

[Spend (Total Sales) Segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8QLl.png)

[Student (Enrollment) Population](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSGNu.png)

This is the format that I expect to create for the matrix that works dynamically with other slicers.

[Segmented Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Aik9.png)

So far, I created both segmented tables with DAX as above.

Also, below are my measures for enrollment and spend segment. They don't work because the measures need to be merged into one, meeting the condition of both segmented conditions.

```
Sales District Counts (Spend Tier) = 

       // HASONEVALUE('Date'[Year]),
    VAR SalesDistrictSegment = 
        FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED(QISsmmSalesDistrictEntities),
            VAR SalesOfSalesDistrict = [Total Sales] 
            VAR SegmentforSalesDistrict =
                FILTER(
                    'Spend Tier',
                    NOT ISBLANK(SalesOfSalesDistrict) &&
                    'Spend Tier'[Min] <= SalesOfSalesDistrict &&
                    'Spend Tier'[Max] > SalesOfSalesDistrict
                )
            VAR IsSalesDistrictInSegments = NOT ISEMPTY(SegmentforSalesDistrict)
        RETURN IsSalesDistrictInSegments
        )

    VAR Result =
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS(QISsmmSalesDistrictEntities),
            KEEPFILTERS(SalesDistrictSegment)
        )
    RETURN
        Result
```

```
Sales District Counts (Enrollment) = 

        //HASONEVALUE('Date'[Year]),
    VAR SalesDistrictSegment = 
        FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED(QISsmmSalesDistrictEntities),
            VAR SalesOfSalesDistrict = [Total Population]
            VAR SegmentforSalesDistrict =
                FILTER(
                    'Enrollment Tier',
                    NOT ISBLANK(SalesOfSalesDistrict) &&
                    'Enrollment Tier'[Min] <= SalesOfSalesDistrict &&
                    'Enrollment Tier'[Max] > SalesOfSalesDistrict
                )
            VAR IsSalesDistrictInSegments = NOT ISEMPTY(SegmentforSalesDistrict)
        RETURN IsSalesDistrictInSegments
        )

    VAR Result =
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS(QISsmmSalesDistrictEntities),
            KEEPFILTERS(SalesDistrictSegment)
        )
    RETURN
        Result
```